# AJAX-ed webpage. How do I bring initial data?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, knockout.js

I have webpage with a tabular data. Right now it uses Knockout.js bindings.

When page loads I make AJAX call to bring data and bind. Basically, page displayed first and than user gets "Loading..." ajax message and data comes. This is nice because page loads fast but browser has to make 2 calls to server (one for page and another for data).

If user want to refresh data - it also works nicely same way.

I would like to know HOW do I load ViewModel data together with page? Any way I can avoid double-trip to server? I'd like to somehow include JSON on initial page load and then work with it and refresh it using AJAX.

EDIT:

I got it working, not sure if there is any gotchas with a way I did it:

HTML:

```
<div id="initialData" style="display: none;"><asp:Literal ID="initialDataLiteral" runat="server" EnableViewState="False"/></div>
```

SERVER CODE:

```
// Prepare initial data for page
            var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(DataEnvelope));
            serializer.WriteObject(memoryStream, GetShipments(DateTime.Now.Date.AddMonths(-2).ToShortDateString(), DateTime.Now.Date.ToShortDateString()));
            memoryStream.Position = 0;
            var streamreader = new StreamReader(memoryStream);
            this.initialDataLiteral.Text = streamreader.ReadToEnd();
```

On Knockout side it's easy, I just take string out, convert to JSON and go with it..

```
// Page comes with preloaded data. Let's set VM properties
        var initialData = $.parseJSON($("#initialData").text());
        vm.tripData(ko.utils.arrayMap(initialData.Shipments, function (i) { return new shipment(i); }));
```

Later when user hit's refresh they get same data via AJAX call. Is there any drawbacks to having it like this? Obviously View source gives bunch of JSON "stuff". I still think page is more compact and first load faster comparing to fully-ajaxed loading..

Comment: Sure, but usually the point of using ajax is that your page doesn't hold up for data. You can load the page, then load the data later instead of waiting for it initially.

Comment: It's annoying when you see empty page and data arrives later. It's only this first load I'm trying to make more optimized

Comment: These posts might be helpful:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7638127/how-to-hold-page-render-until-an-ajax-call-completes

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/191483/how-do-i-submit-an-ajax-request-before-the-page-is-loaded

Comment: I'm essentially doing the same thing with my current app -- I JSON-serialize the data and send it along with the HTML on first load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't specify what server-side technology you're using, but you did at least tag the question with `asp.net`. This is the pattern I use with ASP.NET MVC, so if you're using Web Forms you may have to adjust it.

```
var modelData = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));

var MyViewModel = function (data) {
    var model = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);

    // any additional observables, computeds, methods, etc., i.e.
    // model.SomethingNotOnModel = ko.computed();

    return model;
};

var viewModel = MyViewModel(modelData);
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Knockout's mapping plugin will automatically create observables for whatever properties exist on the data object fed to it, so you don't need to specify those manually, unless you need to change them.

**UPDATE**

Based on @Rich's comment, I felt I should display a little more clearly how you should actually use this:

**In page**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {    
        var modelData = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
        MyApp.MyView.Init(modelData);
    });
</script>
```

**External JS**

```
MyApp = MyApp || {};

MyApp.MyView = function () {
    var _init = function (data) {
        var viewModel = MyApp.MyView.MyViewModel(data);
        ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
        // anything else that should happen on page load
    };

    return {
        Init: _init
    };
}();

MyApp.MyView.MyViewModel = function (data) {
    var model = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);

    // any additional observables, computeds, methods, etc., i.e.
    // model.SomethingNotOnModel = ko.computed();

    return model;
};
```

Comment: I use Web Forms. Already coded it by encoding JSON on server (reusing same function I use for WebMethod). I only concerned about placement on page. Will edit main question..

Comment: Well, pending your update, I think the pattern still applies. The idea is that you're essentially dependency injecting your Knockout view model so that it creates itself from some data object. If you just have a JSON string, you can pass that to the view model instead and then use `ko.mapping.fromJSON(jsonString)`.

Comment: I posted my update. Idea is the same I beleive but I wonder about my approach. Can I hide this data somehow from page?

Comment: No, that's the part you can't avoid. JS runs client-side, so it can't access anything that does not also exist client-side without AJAX. So if you want to avoid the initial AJAX, you have to just dump the data somewhere on the page.

Comment: Ok, just wanted to make sure I did it correctly and there is nothing better/slicker. Just learning my steps. Thanks!

Comment: I like Chris's idea a little better. It's a pattern I use sometimes as well. The idea to just dynamically within the page to generate the javascript variable seems a little cleaner than creating an extra DOM element to hold the value. Though I only generate the first line within the view. The rest I keep in regular .js files.

Comment: @Rich: definitely. In fact, I'll update my answer to display that a little more clearly. Everything else should be properly namespaced and put in external JS.